# Error Loading File

Tags: c#

I made big progress, but now i have a problem with the loading of a file. Here is the class with the file-loading method again:

```
public class BunchOfDeliverables
{
    private List<Person> myPersons;
    private List<Deliverable> myDeliverables;

    public BunchOfDeliverables()
    {
        this.myPersons = new List<Person>();
        this.myDeliverables = new List<Deliverable>();
    }

    public List<Person> Persons { get { return this.myPersons; } }
    public List<Deliverable> Deliverables { get { return this.myDeliverables; } }

    public void LoadPersonsFromFile(String filename)
    {
        StreamReader sr = null;
        try
        {
            sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
            String name, street, housenr, postalcode, city;
            name = sr.ReadLine();
            while (name != null)
            {
                street = sr.ReadLine();
                housenr = sr.ReadLine();
                postalcode = sr.ReadLine();
                city = sr.ReadLine();
                this.myPersons.Add(new Person(name, street, Convert.ToInt32(housenr), postalcode, city));
                name = sr.ReadLine();
                name = sr.ReadLine(); //and again read a line, because of the delimiter (line with the stars)
            }
        }
        catch (IOException) { }
        finally
        {
            if (sr != null) sr.Close();
        }
    }

    public void LoadDeliverablesFromFile(String filename)
    {
        StreamReader sr = null;
        try
        {
            sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
            String s;
            s = sr.ReadLine();
            while (s != null)
            {
                String[] items = s.Split();
                this.myDeliverables.Add(new Deliverable(Convert.ToInt32(items[0]), Convert.ToInt32(items[1]), this.myPersons[Convert.ToInt32(items[2])]));
                s = sr.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException) { }
        finally
        {
            if (sr != null) sr.Close();
        }
    }


    public void AddPerson(Person p)
    {
        this.myPersons.Add(p);
    }


    public Deliverable FindDeliverable(int id)
    {
        foreach (Deliverable d in this.myDeliverables)
        {
            if (d.ID == id)
            {
                return d;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void AddDeliverable(Deliverable d)
    {
        if (FindDeliverable(d.ID) == null)
        {
            myDeliverables.Add(d);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Be aware: nothing is added!!!");
        }

    }
```

And here - in the form i`ve initialized them:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BunchOfDeliverables d;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        d = new BunchOfDeliverables();
        d.LoadDeliverablesFromFile("../../data/deliverables.txt");
        d.LoadPersonsFromFile("../../data/persons.txt");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        foreach (Person per in d.Persons)
        {

            listBox1.Items.Add(per);
        }


    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void ViewDeliv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        foreach (Deliverable deliv in d.Deliverables)
        {

            listBox1.Items.Add(deliv);
        }
    }
```

Now for the Persons loading file it works like a charm, nothing goes wrong, but once i try to load the Deliverables file the following error occurs:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index" on this line:
>
> "this.myDeliverables.Add(new Deliverable(Convert.ToInt32(items[0]), Convert.ToInt32(items[1]), this.myPersons[Convert.ToInt32(items[2])]));"

Here is how the deliverables file is structured with a small example(without the empty lines):

```
1 350 1
2 700 5
3 360 7
4 360 6
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Firstly, you've provided *way* more code than is actually relevant. You could have cut this down into about 10 lines of code which would still have shown the problem. Secondly, presumably `items` doesn't have three elements for the line that's causing a problem. What diagnostics have you performed? Have you stepped through in a debugger? Added logging?

Comment: I haven`t ran diagnostics or went through a debugger. I am studying computer science in university for 1st year and we still have not done such things, only really basic stuff (this code is not mine, it was given and i just have to add some methods and stuff, but i came to the conclusion that the given code had the error that i wrote above).

Comment: "Here is how the deliverables file is structured with a small example **(without the empty lines):**" *hint:* What do you think will happen if you call `Split` an an empty line?

Comment: Primary directive: never ever put `catch (SomeException) { }` in your code. Either handle the exception or don't catch it.

Comment: @KonstantinHadzhiev: You should learn how to use a debugger before you go *any* further, to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the array `items` has to short elements. So it has only 0, 1 or 2 elements, not 3.

Perhapse your file has an empty line at the end which does not contain information.

Try to modify your while loop with:

```
while(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
    ....
```

You could also check first if the number of items in your array equals 3.

If all this does not help, put a breakpoint at that line. Each time your code breaks, check out the value of `s` and `items`.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
String[] items = s.Split();
this.myDeliverables.Add(new Deliverable(Convert.ToInt32(items[0]), Convert.ToInt32(items[1]), this.myPersons[Convert.ToInt32(items[2])]));
```

is assuming that every line in your input file has at least three space-separated items.

If a line contains less items, you will get this error. It could mean an error in your input file, or it could mean that there is valid data in the file that your parsing isn't accounting for.

To simply skip over the lines without enough data, you could do this:

```
String[] items = s.Split();
if (items.Count >= 3)
    this.myDeliverables.Add(new Deliverable(Convert.ToInt32(items[0]), Convert.ToInt32(items[1]), this.myPersons[Convert.ToInt32(items[2])]));
```

However, whether that is a valid thing to do depends on whether the error is in the data file or your expected format for that data. If it's an error in the data, you should really display an error message.